# How to get devicetoken of iphone for push notification?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to use the push notification service provided by apple but I am not able to get the device token required for pushing the notification. I am using the following code for retrieving the device token

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)devToken
{
     const void *devTokenBytes = [devToken bytes];
     NSLog(@"devToken=%@",devTokenBytes);
     //[self alertNotice:@"" withMSG:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"devToken=%@",devToken] cancleButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK",@"") otherButtonTitle:@""];
    //self.registered = YES;
    //[self sendProviderDeviceToken:devTokenBytes]; // custom method    
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)err
{
    NSLog(@"Error in registration. Error: %@", err);
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{   
    for (id key in userInfo)
    {
         NSLog(@"key: %@, value: %@", key, [userInfo objectForKey:key]);
    }    
}
```

I am registering for the remote notification using the following code

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] 
 registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
 (UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | 
  UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | 
  UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
```

Can anyone help me with this...

I am having the following warning message in the console window

```
warning: Unable to read symbols for "/Library/MobileSubstrate/MobileSubstrate.dylib" (file not found).
```

Is it to do something with the jailbroken iphone...

Thanx in advance...

Comment: have you been able to solve his issue because I am also testing my app on jailbroken iphone and none of the delegate methods are called when I try to get device token from apple. Also I am having same warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that you have answered it yourself. Jailbroken iPhones will have problems receiving push notifications, as far as i know, but i am not absolutely sure. Were you able to get development/production certificates using this iPhone's UDID for installing apps?

Comment: I have development certificate for this app. I have other apps installed on this iphone which are not developed by me but I do get push notification for these apps... Can anyone help me with this....

Comment: If this is true at all, it certainly isn't *universally* true.  I have a jailbroken iOS 5 iPhone 4, and all my push notifications work fine.  Did you mean to say "jailbreak **apps**"?  I could see how apps that are not signed with APNS-enabled provisioning profiles wouldn't work properly.  But, that's different than the device itself not receiving push notifications, right?